# Print every row and column index for numpy matrix along with their values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d matrix that shows the status of the seats in a theater, where S means the seat is vacant and B are the seats that are booked.

```
seats = [['S' 'B' 'B' 'S' 'S']
 ['S' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S']
 ['S' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'S']
 ['S' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S']
 ['S' 'B' 'S' 'B' 'S']]
```

I would like to print the results similar to the following manner which I need to store in a database:

```
seats[0][0] = 'S'
seats[0][1] = 'B'
.
.
.
seats[5][5] = 'S'
```

Comment: Is printing your objective or transforming the seats into a row-wise order your objective? If it is the later, there are other ways to do that other than using nested for loops

Comment: @sai I needed to use the row column index to be stored in the seats database along with the status to later be used to show the seating arrangement. Can you please mention the other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(seats)):
    for j in range(len(seats[i])):
        print(i,j, seats[i][j])
```

Comment: Always happy to help! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of in which format you need the information but here is a way to go about it-

```py
import numpy as np

seats = np.array([['S', 'B', 'B', 'S', 'S'],
                  ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'],
                  ['S', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'S'],
                  ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'],
                  ['S', 'B', 'S', 'B', 'S']])

indices = np.indices(seats.shape)
print(np.hstack((indices[0].reshape(-1, 1), indices[1].reshape(-1, 1), seats.reshape(-1, 1))))
```

```
[['0' '0' 'S']
 ['0' '1' 'B']
 ['0' '2' 'B']
 ['0' '3' 'S']
 ['0' '4' 'S']
 ['1' '0' 'S']
 ['1' '1' 'S']
 ['1' '2' 'S']
 ['1' '3' 'S']
 ['1' '4' 'S']
 ['2' '0' 'S']
 ['2' '1' 'B']
 ['2' '2' 'B']
 ['2' '3' 'B']
 ['2' '4' 'S']
 ['3' '0' 'S']
 ['3' '1' 'S']
 ['3' '2' 'S']
 ['3' '3' 'S']
 ['3' '4' 'S']
 ['4' '0' 'S']
 ['4' '1' 'B']
 ['4' '2' 'S']
 ['4' '3' 'B']
 ['4' '4' 'S']]
```